# Create dynamic fields in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have table `user` with fields in additional custom fields for user that added by admin.
[sql click this to diagram explain this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYj1l.jpg)

so i want to create `Register` page with user fields and custom fields.
i get `FiledType` and `FieldName` to list.
in Controler:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.CustomeFields = userCustomeFields.GetCustomeField();
        return View();
    }
```

UserField model:

```
public class UserField
{
    public string FieldName;
    public string FieldTypeName;
}
```

so i want to create dynamic fields in cshtml file.
i wrote this code:
**Update:**

```
 @foreach (var item in ViewBag.CustomeFields)
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            @*@Html.LabelFor(i=>item.FieldTypeName  , htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })*@
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @if (item.FieldTypeName == "Textbox")
                {
                    @Html.TextBox(item.FieldName)
                }
                </div>
            </div>
                    @*@Html.Editor(item.FieldName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
                    }
```

but i give error!
`HtmlHelper<User>' has no applicable method named 'TextBox' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.`
i don't know is my way correct or not?!

Comment: What is the error you are getting?
Maybe there is a syntax problem. There is no `{` after the if statement. Try something like

`@if(item.FieldTypeName=="Textbox") {
   <text>@Html.TextBox(item.FieldName)</text>`

Comment: @glia i get this error: HtmlHelper<User>' has no applicable method named 'TextBox' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.

Comment: Okay, the error describes the problem well. From `ViewBag` you get objects of type `dynamic`, that's "worse" than of type object. You have to cast it for example like this `@foreach(UserField item in ViewBag.CustomFields) {` or`@Html.TextBox(((UserField)item).FieldName)` or `@Html.TextBox((string)item.FieldName)`.

Comment: @gila Thank you!  but how to apply htmlAttributes to @Html.TextBox() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here again the answar to your first question, in case you want t mark it as a correct answer ^^

You have to cast it for example like this

```
@foreach(UserField item in ViewBag.CustomFields) {
```

or

```
@Html.TextBox(((UserField)item).FieldName)
```

or 
    @Html.TextBox((string)item.FieldName)

For the attributes you can use a anonymouse type object with `new { ... }`

```
@Html.TextBox("nameOfTheTexbox", "initialValue", new { @class ="myCssClass myOtherCssClass", disabled = "disabled" })
```